# Function can't be called for some reason -- using localStorage for a script

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is console log the amount of unread messages within a script. The rules are: *if the chat window is minimized, add one when a message is received*, and, *when the chat window is maximized, set the count back to zero*. All stored to be persistent so page reloads or navigation won't change the count. Here's my script.

```
      count = 0;
      let is_minimized = true;

      var chatServiceOptions = {
        license: "*SECRET*", // ie '1234567'
        group: 4, // ie 22,
        customer: {
          name: "Development Account",
          timezone: "Europe/London"
        },
        plugins: [

// this is where the code starts          
          function countAdd() {
                localStorage.count = count++;
              },
//this is just calling the API, when a chat is available          
          function (chatService) {
           chatService.register('ready', function() {

             // when chat window is closed, ensure is_minimized is true
             chatService.events.on('LC_on_chat_window_minimized', data => {
               is_minimized = true
             });

             // when chat window is opened, set is_minimized to false
         chatService.events.on('LC_on_chat_window_opened', data => {
                count = 0    
                is_minimized = false
             });

             chatService.events.on('LC_on_message', function(data) {
               // set the window minimized to a variable 
               var LC_API = LC_API || {};
                  LC_API.on_chat_window_minimized = function() {
                    is_minimized = true;
               };

               // output the data of the incoming/outgoing message
               console.log(data);
               // check that it comes from an agent and the chat window is minimized
               // if it is, add +1 to unread message count
               if (data.user_type ==='agent' && is_minimized == true) {
                countAdd(); } 
               // if its maximized, set unread count to zero
               else { localStorage.count = 0; };

               // display number of unread messages
               console.log('unread messages: ' + localStorage.getItem('count'));
             });
           })
          }
     ],
      };
      var LC_API = LC_API || {};
LC_API.on_message = function(data) {
  console.log(data)
  alert("Message " + data.text + " sent by " + data.user_type);
};
    </script>
```

Console is giving me:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: countAdd is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `countAdd` and the other function first, then pass them into the plugins array. Since you are defining them inline, the second function isn't aware of `countAdd`

```js
function countAdd() { }
function otherFn() {
  // uses countAdd in here
}

var chatServiceOptions = {
  license: "*SECRET*", // ie '1234567'
  group: 4, // ie 22,
  customer: {
    name: "Development Account",
    timezone: "Europe/London"
  },
  // provide both functions to the plugins property
  plugins: [countAdd, otherFn]
}
```

Comment: Oh perfect! So just to clarify, you're saying just put countAdd outside of that function.

Comment: @jorts Yes, defining them directly in the plugins array is ok as long as they don't reference each other, but because you are using `countArray` inside the other, it needs to be defined prior to being used. So you could just move `countArray` up instead of both

Comment: Thank you so much, I think this fixed the issue.