# localStorage not being reset to zero after event

Tags: javascript

Similar to [my previous question I asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60454470/function-cant-be-called-for-some-reason-using-localstorage-for-a-script), I'm trying to count how many 'unread messages' there are via this API. When "`is_minimized = true`", the number in `count` should increase by `1`. When "`is_minimized = false`", the variable `count` should be reset to `0`. This needs to be persistent, which is why I'm using `localStorage`.

*The problem*: When `is_minimized = false`, `count` is displaying `0` in the console. However, when attempting again `is_minimized = true`, the variable picks up where it last left off. I.E., if `count` was previously `4`, then `is_minimized = false` console logs `0`, then `is_minimized = true` again, the number is appearing as `5`, which is wrong, it should be `1`.

Here is the current code:

```
      count = localStorage.getItem('count');
      if (count == null) {
        count = 0
      }

      let is_minimized = true;

      function countAdd() {

                localStorage.setItem('count', ++count);

                           };

      var chatServiceOptions = {
        license: "**hidden for privacy**", // ie '1234567'
        group: 4, // ie 22,
        customer: {
          name: "Development Account",
          timezone: "Europe/London"
        },
        plugins: [
          function (chatService) {
           chatService.register('ready', function() {

             // when chat window is closed, ensure is_minimized is true
             chatService.events.on('LC_on_chat_window_minimized', data => {
               is_minimized = true
             });

             // when chat window is opened, set is_minimized to false
         chatService.events.on('LC_on_chat_window_opened', data => {
               // localStorage.setItem('count', 0);    
                is_minimized = false
             });

             chatService.events.on('LC_on_message', function(data) {
               // set the window minimized to a variable 
               var LC_API = LC_API || {};
                  LC_API.on_chat_window_minimized = function() {
                    is_minimized = true;
               };

               // output the data of the incoming/outgoing message
               console.log(data);
               // check that it comes from an agent and the chat window is minimized
               // if it is, add +1 to unread message count
               if (data.user_type === 'agent' && is_minimized == true) {
                countAdd(); } 
               // if its maximized, set unread count to zero
               else if (is_minimized == false) { localStorage.setItem('count', '0'); };

               // display number of unread messages
               console.log('unread messages: ' + localStorage.getItem('count'));
             });
           })
          }
     ],
      };



      var LC_API = LC_API || {};
LC_API.on_message = function(data) {
  console.log(data)
  alert("Message " + data.text + " sent by " + data.user_type);
};
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `count = localStorage.getItem('count');` is global to the file.
Secondly, `count` doesn't change every time you set your `localStorage`.
So, get the current count every time you call countAdd and then increment and set the count in localStorage

```
function countAdd() {
  var persistedCount = localStorage.getItem('count') ;

  localStorage.setItem('count', ++persistedCount);

};
```

I hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to clear 'count' before resetting it to 0 in the else if block...

Let's modify this line:

> else if (is_minimized == false) { localStorage.setItem('count', '0');
>   };

To:

```
 else if(is_minimized == false)
{
  localStorage.removeItem('count');
  //now declare count and set it to 0
  localStorage.setItem('count', '0');
}
```

Hope this helps.